# Start external program without hardcoding the path

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am making a GUI that is supposed to be run on different computers. In the script I need to open an external program and run a macro through this program.I am using subprocess to do so. The problem is that without hardcoding the path I am not able to find the program. I cannot hardcode the path, because the program might be in different directories on different computers. Is this possible to do?

Code:

```
from subprocess import *

def call_dos(self, program, *args):

    proc = call([program, args])
    if proc:
        logging.warning('Calling failed')
    else:
        logging.info('Calling successful')

def partone(self, *args):
    try:
        self.call_dos("Myprogram.exe", r"C:\Mymacro.mko")
    finally:
        self.partone()
```

The error message:

```
Traceback:
    'Calling failed'
```

Thank you for any replies!

Comment: requirement: `"Myprogram.exe"` must be in system path. This is unrelated to any python question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check that `Myprogram.exe` is callable, i.e. in system path.

For windows, either set it in user or system environment by appending the actual directory where the exe is located to the `PATH` environment variable.

To make sure that users don't blame your program for their bad installation, you could add a check so the error is human-readable:

```
import distutils.spawn
if not distutils.spawn.find_executable("Myprogram.exe"):
     raise Exception("{} is not in the path, add it to path and retry".format("Myprogram.exe"))
```

You can also distribute the program alongside your script (same directory), so you're sure it's found (if doesn't need a deep installation). In that case, do:

```
self.call_dos(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Myprogram.exe"), r"C:\Mymacro.mko")
```